# How to check ajax is completed successfully with jQuery editable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jeditable

I am using [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) for inline editing.

```
$(".video_content_right .project_description").editable(BASE_URL+"/update/description", {
    indicator: "<img src='" + BASE_URL + "/resources/assets/front/images/indicator.gif'>",
    tooltip: "",
    type: "textarea",
    event: "mouseover",
    style: "inherit",
    submitdata: function() {
        return {
            projectidx: $(".my-showcaseowl-carousel .projectidx").eq(currentIndex).val()
        }
    },
    submit: 'Update'
});
```

Now I want to check if the AJAX request has completed. I have tried with the below, but it is not working:

```
success: function(data) {}
```

Any Idea how to check the AJAX request has completed successfully?

Comment: Given the [documentation](https://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/#options) the `success` property is exactly what you should be using, is there a reason it doesn't work for you? Also there is no mention in the docs of a `submitdata`property, so I'm unsure what the purpose of that part of your code is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am following this document: `http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add global ajaxSuccess:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions, data) {
   if (ajaxOptions.url == BASE_URL+"/update/description") {
       // do some action
   }
});
```